# ¿Cómo hacer una tabla en Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Alguien que me pueda decir, como generar una tabla en `Crystal Report`, según lo que yo leí es que la tabla se genera sola al poner los campos de datos en la sección de detalle pero no funciona, en vez de mostrarme los 3 o 4 registros que hay, solo me muestra uno.

Estoy usando `C#` y los datos los paso a través de un `dataset`.

Código para pasar los datos:

```
if (txtProveedor.Text != "")
{
    datos ds = new datos(); //creamos el objeto dataset
    frmVerReporte ver;//creamos el objeto para visor de reportes
    //llenamos el dataset
    ds.Tabla.Rows.Add(txtProveedor.Text, txtCliente.Text, txtFecha.Text,
    dgv_materiales.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
    dgv_materiales.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
    dgv_materiales.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
    dgv_materiales.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
    dgv_materiales.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
    dgv_materiales.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
    dgv_materiales.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
    dgv_materiales.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString()
);
//iniciamos el visor del reporte y mandamos los datos de la tabla.
ver = new frmVerReporte(ds.Tabla);
ver.Show();
```

Y solo me muestra el reporte así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por decir a este reporte le falta que muestre otros 3 registros.

Comment: ¿Qué estas usando para generar el reporte de Crystal Report, Complemento de Visual Studio o IDE de Crystal report?

Comment: es complemento de Visual Studio

Comment: ¿si estás poniendo esa parte en la sección detalles?

Comment: los encabezado que son las letras en negrita estan en encabezado de pagina, los totales en pie del informe, y lo demas en la parte de detalles

Comment: Hola, nuevamente, estoy mirando que solo estas llenando un registro en tú lógica (¿Ese if, no se encuentra dentro de un ciclo?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de la siguiente manera:

```
if (txtProveedor.Text != "")
{
    datos ds = new datos(); //creamos el objeto dataset
    frmVerReporte ver;//creamos el objeto para visor de reportes
    //llenamos el dataset
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv_materiales.Rows){
        ds.Tabla.Rows.Add(txtProveedor.Text, txtCliente.Text, txtFecha.Text,
        row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
        row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()
    }

);
//iniciamos el visor del reporte y mandamos los datos de la tabla.
ver = new frmVerReporte(ds.Tabla);
ver.Show();
```

Comment: si resulto, pero en vez de ponerme los datos que son, me repite la primera fila

Comment: no es cierto, era un error mio,jajajaja genial si me funciono, muchas gracias